# Selecting checkbox value that is nested in several spans

Tags: jquery, class, dynamic, checkbox, nested

I need dynamic form validation for a form that I have made for a friend's WordPress site. I used a form plugin so it would be easier for them to use in the future.

I need to have certain fields become conditionally required based on the input from other fields. For instance, if a person checks "yes" in a checkbox that they have pets, then I would need a bunch of other pet related fields to become required and maybe hide themselves as well. I want to do this by just adding/removing classes when input values change.

The checkbox on the site is so heavily nested in spans because of the plugin and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access the value of of my Check Boxes.

jsFiddle if the code below is too messy -> http://jsfiddle.net/ebgranger/cjsg2/3/

**HTML**

```
<p>Do you currently have pets?
        <br /> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-243"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required petsCheckBox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-243[]" value="Yes" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-243[]" value="No" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">No</span></span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.checkbox-243 .wpcf7-checkbox .wpcf-list-item input').blur(function () {
if (this:checkbox:checked = "Yes") { 
    $(this).parents('p').addClass('red');
} else if (this:checkbox:checked == "No") {
    $(this).parents('p').removeClass('red');
} 
});
```

This code isn't working too well. I have the logic down for how I want this to work, but I need to learn more about jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax to target the checkbox.

Use `find` to get it first.

Also checked property **is boolean.. Not a string**

```
if ( $(this).find('checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    // Add class
} else {
   // remove class
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('.checkbox-243 .petsCheckBox input[value="Yes"]').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.is(':checked')) {
        $this.closest('p').addClass('red');
    } else {
        $this.closest('p').removeClass('red');
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cjsg2/4/)**

Comment: I modified my code but it does not currently work. Am I targeting the ancestor paragraph tag properly? Thank you for the response.

Comment: I could not understand your question property.. The only inputs inside the selector that you posted are checkbox inputs.. I don't see a textbox

Comment: the solution presented did not seem to solved the problem in my js       fiddle     $(this).parents('p').removeClass('red'); As an example I'm just trying to change the background color of the parent paragraph tag at the very top of the HTML code.

Comment: So if the checkbox is selected, what all elements should be highlighted.. Blur event does not make sense for a checkbox

Comment: just the p tag @Sushanth

Comment: @EdwardGranger.. Check the updated code.. You were using the wrong selector